# How to LINQ DataTable with group by and order by to deduplicate data

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, linq-to-objects

I have the following datatable

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | B | 2 |
| A | C | 1 |

The **Col1** and **Col2** is the unique key so the first and the second row is duplicated.
The **Col3** differ so I would like to have an option to setup condition which row to select. The condition could be for example *Take grouped row where Col3 is the greatest*. The result would be.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2 |
| A | C | 1 |

How to use LINQ for that? I tried variations of following

**Datatable setup**

```
var datatable = new DataTable();
            
datatable.Columns.Add("Col1");
datatable.Columns.Add("Col2");
datatable.Columns.Add("Col3");

// this row should not be in the result
var row1 = datatable.NewRow(); 
row1.ItemArray = new[] { "A", "B", "1" };
datatable.Rows.Add(row1);

var row2 = datatable.NewRow();
row2.ItemArray = new[] { "A", "B", "2" };
datatable.Rows.Add(row2);

var row3 = datatable.NewRow();
row3.ItemArray = new[] { "A", "C", "1" };
datatable.Rows.Add(row3);
```

**Query attempt**

It can be query expression or fluent based, it does not matter.

```
var result =
from record in datatable.AsEnumerable()
group record by new { record.Field<string>("Col1"), record.Field<string>("Col2") } into g
let row =
(
     from groupedItem in groupedItems
     order by groupedItem.Field<string>("Col3") desc
     select groupedItem
).First()
select row;
```

When there is **record.Field**, I am getting an exception

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator

I'm not experienced in complicated LINQ queries, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like compiler is not able to infer the type of the columns you have in the datatable, try naming them in anonymous properties like:

```
 group record by new 
                 { 
                    Col1 = record.Field<string>("Col1"),
                    Col2 = record.Field<string>("Col2") 
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The working solution, thanks to @Ehsan Sajjad is

```
var result =
from record in datatable.AsEnumerable()
group record by new { 
    Col1 = record.Field<string>("Col1"), 
    Col2 = record.Field<string>("Col2"),
} into g
let selectedItem =
(
    from item in g
    orderby item.Field<string>("Col3") descending
    select item
).First()
select selectedItem;
```